# Switch between selenium driver tabs without waiting for response of current request

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, timedelay

I want to scrape value from different pages of the same website. Single page taking much time.
I want to switch the tab without the wait for a response in selenium.

e.g

`driver.get("https://test.com")`
for example, it will take 10 seconds.
Now I want to create a new tab and switch to a new tab so we can save that time. then return back to previous tabs and then parse the details. In this way, we can save execution time.

Comment: What code have you tried ? there are multiple and duplicated post like this in stackoverflow, if you have tried something update your post with the same.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.